# Trying to capture enclosed string between asterisks **(str)**

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to replace `**SomeStr**` to `<b>SomeStr</b>`. I almost achieved what I want. The main problem I have with the code below is that it captures

```
**def*****yo**
```

into 3 pieces `**def**`,`*`,`**yo**` when I think it should be `**def**`, `***yo**` so it will be converted into `<b>def</b><b>*yo</b>`. One asterisk should not end the match but that's what is happening.

```js
const pattern = /(\*\*)([^\*\*]*)(\*\*)/g;

let str = `* abc **
* **def****yo**
*`

const replacer = function(match, first, inner, last){
  return "<b>"+inner+"</b>"
}

str = str.replace(pattern, replacer)
console.log(str)
```

I wish I knew what to fiddle with.

Comment: `([^\*\*]*)` says to match on 0 or more characters that are not `*`. `^` as the first character of a `[]` (character set) says to not match on any of the characters.  Including the same character twice in the set doesn't make it not match only if they repeat

Comment: No need to escape `*` as `\*` inside the `[^...]` brackets.

Comment: Try ``str.replace(/\*\*([^*]*(?:\*(?!\*)[^*]*)*)\*\*/g, '<b>$1</b>')``

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That is a real nice solution

Comment: Yeah, but I am not sure - the current sample string is line-based, and requires `str = str.replace(/\*\*([^*\n]*(?:\*(?!\*)[^*\n]*)*)\*\*/g, '<b>$1</b>')`. @PuffedRiceCrackers, does it have to work on per-line basis or across the lines? If the latter, your example is not quite clear.

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying. I didn't fully understand the requirements myself when I first started. It was line-based.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Took me a long time to understand it but I finally made it and also revised it to process `**ab***` as well. Thank you so much for the help and kind explanation. This still has some issues as in `**a**b**c**` or `****` but I will try to work on it.

Comment: `\*\*((?:[^*\n]*(?<!\*)\*)*[^*\n]*(?:\*(?!\*)[^*\n]*)*)\*\*`

Comment: @PuffedRiceCrackers If you explain the issue with *my* solution,  I will try to help.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your answer worked perfectly except in a case like `**ab***` because it grouped the string as `**ab**` and with the end result being `<b>ab</b>*` instead of `<b>ab*</b>` Not even your mistake because I didn't clarify how I want to handle * in the middle. So I added  `[^*\n]*(?:\*(?!\*)` to handle a string like `ab*` although it yielded another problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```js
var str = " **def*****yo**";
var regex = /\*\*([^*]*(?:\*(?!\*)[^*]*)*)\*\*/g;
var replacement = '<b>$1</b>';
console.log(str.replace(regex, replacement))
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dO8J3d/2).

If you need to only match within lines, without matching across line breaks, add newlines to the negated character class and use

```
var regex = /\*\*([^*\n]*(?:\*(?!\*)[^*\n]*)*)\*\*/g;
```

**Pattern details**

- `\*\*` - a `**` substring
- `([^*]*(?:\*(?!\*)[^*]*)*)` - Group 1: zero or more chars other than asterisks (`[^*]*`) followed with zero or more sequences of a `*` not followed with another `*` and then followed with zero or more chars other than asterisks
- `\*\*` - a `**` substring

The `$1` in the replacement pattern stands for Group 1 value, no need to use callables in the replacement argument to access group values.

Answer (score 0):

Currently your Regex expression is looking for two pairs of asterisks 'bracketing' a group of 0 or more of anything other than an asterix (which you have twice here, which I believe is redundant within a set like this). That means you'll never have a '***' at the beginning of a matched string because an asterix cannot be between two pairs of asterixes as per your Regex.

If you **definitely** want to match as many characters as possible within two pairs of asterixes, you need to start by making sure that you're not excluding asterixes from matching within the central group.

Partly the problem is that you need to think about your logic a bit harder - why should it be `***yo**` when `**yo**` is equally valid (in both cases the string begins and ends with two asterixes, and in the second case the string actually begins and ends with ONLY two asterixes, so could be argued to be an even 'better' match).  I'm not sure the logic you think you want is the logic you actually require.

https://regexr.com/ is really helpful for testing out and playing with Regex expressions until you match the phrase you want. Just from initial messing about with your dummy text, `(\*\*)([.\w\*]+)(\*\*)/g` seems to work, but you'll need to test it more.